# Using the correct path with namespaces for parsing XML (in VBA)

Tags: xml, vba, namespaces, ebay-api, xml-documentation

I'm struggling to wrap my head around namespaces & paths wrt parsing XML using VBA. Here I have some very simple XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetOrdersResponse
xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2016-09-26T08:49:18.274Z</Timestamp>
Ack 
<Version>983</Version>
<Build>E983_INTL_APIXO_18098703_R1</Build>
<OrderArray>
    <Order>
        <OrderID>252363798635-1903344147015</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    </Order>
    <Order>
        <OrderID>261505550993-1887803672016</OrderID>
        <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
    </Order>
</OrderArray>
</GetOrdersResponse>
```

I have set the namespace up in VBA like this (this was found from another stackoverflow question!)...

```
Dim xmlNamespaces As String
xmlNamespaces = "xmlns:doc='urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents'"
objxmldoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces
objxmldoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
```

My question is how do I reference the actual XML data fields I need?

Here's a command I typically use...

```
Set Ordercount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//OrderID")
Debug.Print "Total Number of Orders : " & Ordercount.length
```

but it's returning a count of 0, so clearly my reference path is wrong - it's the syntax ("//OrderID") that I'm uncertain about. So what should the syntax be for pulling in the data for  &  in the XML pasted above? (i.e. bearing in mind my code's namespace declarations)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are close enough! If you want to get number of elements:OrderID you can simply use Count property. Like this:

```
Ordercount = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//OrderID").Count
Debug.Print "Total Number of Orders : " & Ordercount
```

Comment: Many thanks...it was that final bit of info I needed (brain fog)